# adding a name to existing LN group distribution and new individuals do not receive email

Tags: lotus-notes, distribution-list

I made a recent edit to an existing group distribution to add a person. I've saved it. I see it in the detail of the group listing but plugging it into an email, the naming convention pops up, but **not all people on the distribution actually receive the email**.

I tried deleting and re-adding the new person. I tried closing out then open up tto the detail, and all names show.

How do i solve for this?

Comment: So some of the people receive the email and some do not? What is the difference between the two sets of people?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the same directory that you are editing, not an old local replica or a server copy that hasn't received the updates yet.